# Why function in if condition is not hoisted in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-2017

How can a `variable` declared in `if` condition is hoisted and not `function`?
Example 1:

```
var x = 1;
if(a = 1) {
    x += typeof a;
}
x;    // 1number
a;    // 1
```

When tried same with `function` in `SpiderMonkey` and `V8` hoisting didn't happen. Why not? What happens to function in `if` condition?
Example 2:

```
var x = 1;
if ( function f () { return 9; } ) {
    x += typeof f;
}
x;     // 1undefined
f;     // ReferenceError: f is not defined
```

However when function is defined inside `if` on success function is hoisted
Example 3:

```
var x = 1;
if ( true ) {
    x += typeof f;
    function f() { return 1; }
}
x;    // 1function
f;    // f()
typeof f;   // function
```

Even if condition is false function is hoisted
Example 4:

```
var x = 1;
if ( false ) {
    x += typeof f;
    function f() { return 1; }
}
x;    // 1
f;    // undefined      not ReferenceError: f is not defined
// f still got hoisted
```

What's happing at example 2? Why function is not hoisted when variable did in example 1?

Comment: Function expressions are not hoisted.

Comment: (I fell into the expression `if ( function f () { return 9; } )` trap....) haha

Comment: @RoyiNamir — Being on the right hand side of an assignment is not the only thing that puts the JS parser into expression mode. Being between `(` and `)` does too.

Comment: Yes ..... ^.....I've missed that :)

Comment: @Quentin how that refers to my problem. I know when we assign a function to some variable it doesn't get hoisted. I'm not assigning any value. My function `f` is a `function declaration` and none of then are `function expressions`

Comment: @Quentin even if it's a not `function expressions` I'm using it after not before. and should been available inside `if` as `var f = function () {}; typeof f; // function`. Why this didn't happened?

Comment: @NAVIN — `if ( function f () { return 9; } ) ` — That's a function expression.

Comment: @NAVIN — You aren't assigning the return value of the function expression anywhere, so `f` isn't defined.

Comment: `a = 1` is not a declaration, it is not hoisted. It is an assignment that only works in strict mode. Prepend `"use strict";` to all of your snippets, run them again, and you will get much less surprising results.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks got it